# Can't open Django shell from PyCharm using manage.py shortcut

Tags: django, python-2.7, pycharm

I can run Django shell directly from terminal in PyCharm, but I can't run it from manage.py shortcut (tools -> manage.py task -> shell). But I can do any other operations using this shortcut.

When I am trying to run it using second way nothing happens.

I am using Django 1.7 and PyCharm 4.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try PyCharm preferences.

> Project:  --> Project Interpreter -->  -->
>   Ensure the correct python environment

Also double check your settings under

> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Console --> Python Console

Comment: Python environment is correct 100%. I thing problem is my Python/Django console settings. But I don't know how to check them. All fields have default values (environment is correct)

Comment: Change your Python Interpreter and the Working Directory on the Python/Django console settings. It is available under `Build, Execution, Deployment --> Console`

Comment: Oh! It was very silly question. Django shell works fine. I didn't see that it opens in 'Python Console'. I've looked for it in 'Terminal' tab :(

Comment: @solomkinmv, can you add your last comment as an answer? Pycharm doesn't specify in what "window" it opened the shell and your comment helped me find it.